# Oracle how to archive reference partitioned table

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, partitioning, archive

I am trying to move data from parent table which is interval partitioned, and a child table partitioned by reference, into corresponding archive table structure.

And to my suprise this seemingly simple task is beyond my reach...

I have read about [moving partitioned table to archive](https://badalchowdhary.wordpress.com/2016/05/15/archiving-oracle-partitions/) but it do not tell how to move tables with foregin keys.

I also read about [moving reference partitioned tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-09CE9F52-A5BE-4CFD-8164-867CAF96DDCF.htm#GUID-09CE9F52-A5BE-4CFD-8164-867CAF96DDCF__CHDEJFFI), but this solution does not work for me, giving this error after first statement:

> ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys

So, I have tried my own approach. It gives me even worse error:

> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kkpamRefGet: index], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

You can reproduce my latest attempt like this:

```sql
/*
DROP TABLE CHILD_TABLE
/
DROP TABLE CHILD_TABLE_ARCHIVE
/
DROP TABLE CHILD_TABLE_TMP
/
DROP TABLE PARENT_TABLE
/
DROP TABLE PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE
/
DROP TABLE PARENT_TABLE_TMP
/
*/
-- SAMPLE STRUCTURE
CREATE TABLE PARENT_TABLE
(
    PARTITION_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    PK NUMBER NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (PARTITION_DATE)
INTERVAL( NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'YEAR'))
(  
PARTITION PARTITION_1 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
PARTITION PARTITION_2 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2018-01-01 00:00:00')
)
/
ALTER TABLE PARENT_TABLE ADD (CONSTRAINT PK_PARENT_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (PK) ENABLE VALIDATE)
/
CREATE TABLE CHILD_TABLE
(
    PK NUMBER NOT NULL,
    FK_PARENT NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CHILD_TABLE
    FOREIGN KEY (FK_PARENT) 
    REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE (PK)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ENABLE VALIDATE
)
PARTITION BY REFERENCE (FK_CHILD_TABLE)
/
CREATE TABLE PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE
(
    PARTITION_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    PK NUMBER NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (PARTITION_DATE)
INTERVAL( NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'YEAR'))
(  
PARTITION PARTITION_1 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
PARTITION PARTITION_2 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2018-01-01 00:00:00')
)
/
ALTER TABLE PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE ADD (CONSTRAINT PK_PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE PRIMARY KEY (PK) ENABLE VALIDATE)
/
CREATE TABLE CHILD_TABLE_ARCHIVE
(
    PK NUMBER NOT NULL,
    FK_PARENT NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CHILD_TABLE_ARCHIVE
    FOREIGN KEY (FK_PARENT) 
    REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE (PK)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ENABLE VALIDATE
)
PARTITION BY REFERENCE (FK_CHILD_TABLE_ARCHIVE)
/
CREATE TABLE PARENT_TABLE_TMP AS SELECT * FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE 1 = 2
/
CREATE TABLE CHILD_TABLE_TMP AS SELECT * FROM CHILD_TABLE WHERE 1 = 2
/
-- SAMPLE DATA
INSERT INTO PARENT_TABLE VALUES (TO_DATE('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),1)
/
INSERT INTO PARENT_TABLE VALUES (TO_DATE('2018-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),2)
/
INSERT INTO PARENT_TABLE VALUES (TO_DATE('2019-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),3)
/
INSERT INTO CHILD_TABLE VALUES (1,1)
/
INSERT INTO CHILD_TABLE VALUES (2,2)
/
INSERT INTO CHILD_TABLE VALUES (3,3)
/
-- My last attempt to do this
ALTER TABLE CHILD_TABLE
EXCHANGE PARTITION PARTITION_2
WITH TABLE CHILD_TABLE_TMP
/
ALTER TABLE PARENT_TABLE
EXCHANGE PARTITION FOR (TO_DATE('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
WITH TABLE PARENT_TABLE_TMP
/
--Without this constraint I am geting: ORA-14130: UNIQUE constraints mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
ALTER TABLE PARENT_TABLE_TMP ADD (CONSTRAINT PK_PARENT_TABLE_TMP PRIMARY KEY (PK) ENABLE VALIDATE)
/
ALTER TABLE PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE
EXCHANGE PARTITION FOR (TO_DATE('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
WITH TABLE PARENT_TABLE_TMP
/
--Without this constraint I am geting:  ORA-14128: FOREIGN KEY constraint mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
ALTER TABLE CHILD_TABLE_TMP ADD
CONSTRAINT FK_CHILD_TABLE_TMP
FOREIGN KEY (FK_PARENT) 
REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE (PK)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ENABLE VALIDATE
/
-- And here is something starange...
ALTER TABLE CHILD_TABLE_ARCHIVE
EXCHANGE PARTITION PARTITION_2
WITH TABLE CHILD_TABLE_TMP
/
```

Currently, I am out of ideas how should I do this, and I am starting to wonder should I even try to move this structure to archive... It is partitioned by dates, so can I just let it grow?

I would appreciate any help in this matter. :)

**UPDATE:**

Just as [Francisco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013705/oracle-how-to-archive-reference-partitioned-table?noredirect=1#comment102442372_58013705) suggested, [CASCADE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/cascade-functionality-for-truncate-partition-and-exchange-partition-12cr1#exchange-partition-cascade) option helped with my sample code. Below is my sample code in working condition.

But, in my real life scenario there is more than one child to parent table. And so, when I try to use CASCADe option I get [ORA-14706](http://www.errbay.com/?r=ORCL-DB-12.1&c=ORA-14706). The proposed solution is not to use CASCADE option...

So I still can not archive my tables, and still really need help.

```sql
DROP TABLE CHILD_TABLE
/
DROP TABLE CHILD_TABLE_ARCHIVE
/
DROP TABLE CHILD_TABLE_TMP
/
DROP TABLE PARENT_TABLE
/
DROP TABLE PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE
/
DROP TABLE PARENT_TABLE_TMP
/
-- SAMPLE STRUCTURE
CREATE TABLE PARENT_TABLE
(
    PARTITION_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    PK NUMBER NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (PARTITION_DATE)
INTERVAL( NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'YEAR'))
(  
PARTITION PARTITION_1 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
PARTITION PARTITION_2 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2018-01-01 00:00:00')
)
/
ALTER TABLE PARENT_TABLE ADD (CONSTRAINT PK_PARENT_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (PK) ENABLE VALIDATE)
/
CREATE TABLE CHILD_TABLE
(
    PK NUMBER NOT NULL,
    FK_PARENT NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CHILD_TABLE
    FOREIGN KEY (FK_PARENT) 
    REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE (PK)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ENABLE VALIDATE
)
PARTITION BY REFERENCE (FK_CHILD_TABLE)
/
CREATE TABLE PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE
(
    PARTITION_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    PK NUMBER NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (PARTITION_DATE)
INTERVAL( NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'YEAR'))
(  
PARTITION PARTITION_1 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
PARTITION PARTITION_2 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2018-01-01 00:00:00')
)
/
ALTER TABLE PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE ADD (CONSTRAINT PK_PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE PRIMARY KEY (PK) ENABLE VALIDATE)
/
CREATE TABLE CHILD_TABLE_ARCHIVE
(
    PK NUMBER NOT NULL,
    FK_PARENT NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CHILD_TABLE_ARCHIVE
    FOREIGN KEY (FK_PARENT) 
    REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE (PK)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ENABLE VALIDATE
)
PARTITION BY REFERENCE (FK_CHILD_TABLE_ARCHIVE)
/
CREATE TABLE PARENT_TABLE_TMP AS SELECT * FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE 1 = 2
/
CREATE TABLE CHILD_TABLE_TMP AS SELECT * FROM CHILD_TABLE WHERE 1 = 2
/
ALTER TABLE PARENT_TABLE_TMP ADD (CONSTRAINT PK_PARENT_TABLE_TMP PRIMARY KEY (PK) ENABLE VALIDATE)
/
ALTER TABLE CHILD_TABLE_TMP ADD
CONSTRAINT FK_CHILD_TABLE_TMP
FOREIGN KEY (FK_PARENT) 
REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE_TMP (PK)
ENABLE VALIDATE
/
-- SAMPLE DATA
INSERT INTO PARENT_TABLE VALUES (TO_DATE('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),1)
/
INSERT INTO PARENT_TABLE VALUES (TO_DATE('2018-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),2)
/
INSERT INTO PARENT_TABLE VALUES (TO_DATE('2019-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),3)
/
INSERT INTO CHILD_TABLE VALUES (1,1)
/
INSERT INTO CHILD_TABLE VALUES (2,2)
/
INSERT INTO CHILD_TABLE VALUES (3,3)
/
ALTER TABLE PARENT_TABLE
EXCHANGE PARTITION FOR (TO_DATE('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
WITH TABLE PARENT_TABLE_TMP
CASCADE UPDATE INDEXES
/
ALTER TABLE PARENT_TABLE_ARCHIVE
EXCHANGE PARTITION FOR (TO_DATE('2017-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
WITH TABLE PARENT_TABLE_TMP
CASCADE UPDATE INDEXES
/
```

Comment: Do you have an Oracle Support license? If so, [this looks like the Note you need to read](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2556549_1.html). (I don't have a license myself, so I can't vouch for the note's efficacy.)

Comment: Nope, I do not have one.

Comment: Why are you moving data in a partitioned table into an archive table in the first place?  Just about any use case for an archive table that I can think of has a corresponding solution once you introduce partitioning without moving data out of the table.  Unless you have queries against the table that don't use the partitioning key and have to scan every partition?

Comment: Yes, I have such queries.

Comment: The note mentions using a cascade option on the exchange, for example:
`ALTER TABLE <parent> 
EXCHANGE PARTITION FOR (to_date('19-MAY-2018','dd-MON-yyyy'))
WITH TABLE <exchange_table> cascade update indexes;`
Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

```
-----creating reference partitioning on existing tables having parent child relationship


----------------------------------------consider the following parent and child table---------------------------------------------------
--create the parent table:

create table t1(
  id int,
  action_date   varchar(8),
  constraint t1_pk primary key (id)
);

--create the child table table:
create table t2(
  id int,
  id_t1,
  constraint t2_pk primary key (id),
  constraint t2_fk1 foreign key (id_t1) references t1(id)
);


---insert sample data into parent
insert into t1 values(1,'20170801');
insert into t1 values(2,'20170901');
insert into t1 values(3,'20171001');

---insert sample data into child
insert into t2 values(1,1);
insert into t2 values(2,1);
insert into t2 values(3,1);
insert into t2 values(4,2);
insert into t2 values(5,1);
insert into t2 values(6,2);
insert into t2 values(7,3);



---------------------------------------------------------creating intermediate table for partitioning-----------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------parent table-------------------------
create table t1_part(
  id int,
  action_date   varchar(8),
  constraint t1_part_pk primary key (id)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (action_date)
    (
        PARTITION t1_part_old VALUES LESS THAN ('20171101'),
        PARTITION t1_part_201711 VALUES LESS THAN ('20171201'),
        PARTITION t1_part_201712 VALUES LESS THAN ('20180101'),
    PARTITION t1_part_def VALUES LESS THAN ('99999999')
  );

-------------------dropping constraints-----------------
ALTER TABLE t2 DROP constraint t2_fk1;  
ALTER TABLE t1 DROP constraint t1_pk;
ALTER TABLE t1_part DROP constraint t1_part_pk;

desc t1;
desc t1_part;

-------------------------switch parent data to partitioned table from unpartitionedtable-------------------------------
ALTER TABLE t1_part EXCHANGE PARTITION t1_part_old WITH TABLE t1 WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
ALTER TABLE t1_part EXCHANGE PARTITION t1_part_201711 WITH TABLE t1 WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
ALTER TABLE t1_part EXCHANGE PARTITION t1_part_201712 WITH TABLE t1 WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
ALTER TABLE t1_part EXCHANGE PARTITION t1_part_def WITH TABLE t1 WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;

--------------------------------update stats----------------------------------
EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SYSTEM', 'T1', cascade => TRUE);


ALTER TABLE t1_part add constraint t1_part_pk primary key (id);
--select * from t1_part;

drop table t1;
RENAME t1_part TO t1;
ALTER TABLE t1 RENAME CONSTRAINT t1_part_pk TO t1_pk;
ALTER TABLE t2 add constraint t2_fk1 foreign key (id_t1) references t1(id);  

--------------------------------update stats----------------------------------
EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SYSTEM', 'T1', cascade => TRUE);

----------------------create partitioned child table---------------------------------------------
create table t2_part(
  id int,
  id_t1 not null,
  constraint t2_part_pk primary key (id),
  constraint t2_part_fk1 foreign key (id_t1) references t1(id)
) partition by reference (t2_part_fk1);

alter table t2 modify (id_t1 int not null);

desc t2;
desc t2_part

-------------------------switch child data to partitioned table from unpartitionedtable-------------------------------
ALTER TABLE t2_part EXCHANGE PARTITION t1_part_old WITH TABLE t2 WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
ALTER TABLE t2_part EXCHANGE PARTITION t1_part_201711 WITH TABLE t2 WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
ALTER TABLE t2_part EXCHANGE PARTITION t1_part_201712 WITH TABLE t2 WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
ALTER TABLE t2_part EXCHANGE PARTITION t1_part_def WITH TABLE t2 WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;


--select * from t2_part;
drop table t2;
RENAME t2_part TO t2;
ALTER TABLE t2 RENAME CONSTRAINT t2_part_pk TO t2_pk;
ALTER TABLE t2 RENAME CONSTRAINT t2_part_fk1 TO t2_fk1;

--------------------------------update stats----------------------------------
EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SYSTEM', 'T2', cascade => TRUE);

-----------------------------------check partition info---------------------------------------------
select table_name, partition_name, high_value
from user_tab_partitions
where table_name in ('T1','T2');

desc t1;
desc t2;
-----------------add new parent partition, child partiion will automatically get created thorugh reference paritioning through foreign key t2_part_fk1
ALTER TABLE T1 SPLIT PARTITION t1_part_old AT ('20170701') INTO (PARTITION t1_part_old, PARTITION t1_part_201707) UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
ALTER TABLE T1 SPLIT PARTITION t1_part_201707 AT ('20170801') INTO (PARTITION t1_part_201707, PARTITION t1_part_201708) UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
ALTER TABLE T1 SPLIT PARTITION t1_part_201708 AT ('20170901') INTO (PARTITION t1_part_201708, PARTITION t1_part_201709) UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
ALTER TABLE T1 SPLIT PARTITION t1_part_201709 AT ('20171001') INTO (PARTITION t1_part_201709, PARTITION t1_part_201710) UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;

EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats('SYSTEM', 'T1', cascade => TRUE);

--------------------validating the partitioned data--------------------

select count(*) from T1 partition (T1_PART_OLD);
select * from T1 partition (T1_PART_201708);
select count(*) from T1 partition (T1_PART_201709);
select count(*) from T1 partition (T1_PART_201710);
select count(*) from T1 partition (T1_PART_201711);


select * from T2;
select * from T1;


select count(*) from T2 partition (T1_PART_OLD);
select * from T2 partition (T1_PART_201708);
select count(*) from T2 partition (T1_PART_201709);
select count(*) from T2 partition (T1_PART_201710);
select count(*) from T2 partition (T1_PART_201711);

-------truncate the partition T1_PART_201708 (refering the parent partition) and validate the data
alter table t2 truncate partition T1_PART_201708;
select * from t2;       ----------------- data from 20170801 to 20170831 will be truncated from child

-------truncate the parent record
alter table t1 drop partition T1_PART_201708;
select * from t1;
```

Comment: Follow the step one by one to convert an existing parent child relationship table to reference partition

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer, but I think is not the answer to my quesion - I do not want to partition, unpartitioned tables. I want to move data from partitioned tables into partitioned archive tables with the same structure. :) 
So, and the end of your example we have structure that I want to move to another tables for example t1_arch, t2_arch. :)